# Eyes not following parented rig properly

Tags: animation, rigging, parent

The eyes are parented to the rig with Automatic Weights.
For this instance I want them to just follow the rotation of the body, but the problem is that each eye is also rotating with the "arms" of the rig independently, making a weird animation.
[image: Notice the eye]

Comment: select the eyes in Edit mode, on the right of the Vertex Groups list, click on the dropdown menu and choose Remove from All Groups, then select the group you want to assign the eyes to and click on the Assign button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the root of your issue is in the weight painting. Using automatic weights as a base is fine. However, this results in some vertecies being bound to unrelated bones, causing the issue. You will need to edit these weights. You can do this either in edit mode using the vertex groups: [image], or in weight paint mode, you can follow this tutorial if you need help with that : https://youtu.be/Tl4qTgwQwYw

I hope that you find this helpful.

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot to me, I just have each eye connected to the head and "torso" with no problems now.

Comment: That's awesome. You should  be able to get rid of the body vertex group on the eyes object, but if your happy, then that's great :)